# Access 2010: Automatic update of a value of a field

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

In access 2010:

I have the table "pharmacy" and I have a field called "ph_quantity".
I also have the table "warehouse" and I have a field called "wh_quantity".
In "warehouse" I also have a field called "available_stock".

Whenever I will change "ph_quantity" or "wh_quantity", I want to automatically update the value of "available_stock".

Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two new features in MS Access 2010 that should be of use to you.

> In Access 2010, you can create table fields that calculate values. The
>   calculations can include values from fields in the same table as well
>   as built-in Access functions.

-- http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/add-a-calculated-field-to-a-table-HA101820564.aspx

[Attaching Logic to Data Using Data Macros in Access 2010 Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff973807.aspx)

Comment: @Remou dont think this is right for zinon. Calculated fields only calculate values from the same table. Plus: I think there may be a design problem. How I understand what he intends to do is update the current stock whenever he books out/in products via one of the quantity field. That is best done via a form - a calculated field has no business here.

Comment: @Johanness Point 2 is data macros. I have already mentioned to zinon in a previous post that the database design may need adjustment.

Comment: @Remou: ok I see. looked lik eone link to me - sorry.

Comment: @Johanness Yes, Ι used the second link!